# Initializing an index by table

Tags: oracle, plsql

When i try to run this code:

```
DECLARE

TYPE varray_test IS VARRAY (100) OF NUMBER; 
TYPE nested_table_test IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
TYPE index_by_table_test IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

varray_1 varray_test:= varray_test();
nested_table1 nested_table_test := nested_table_test();
index_by_table1 index_by_table_test := index_by_table_test();

BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line('DONE');
END;
/
```

I get this message:

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 40:
PLS-00222: no function with name 'INDEX_BY_TABLE_TEST' exists in this scope
ORA-06550: line 9, column 17:
PL/SQL: Item ignored

7. index_by_table1 index_by_table_test := index_by_table_test();
8. BEGIN
9. dbms_output.put_line('DONE');
10. END;
11. /
```

Initiazing the varray and the regular nested table works, but for some reason it does not work for the index by table. Please explain why this is, or what I am doin wrong.

Comment: You don't need to initialize associative arrays, so just remove  `:=index_by_table_test()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is an associative array which doesn't have to be initialized before assigning values to it.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     TYPE varray_test IS VARRAY (100) OF NUMBER;
  3
  4     TYPE nested_table_test IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
  5
  6     TYPE index_by_table_test IS TABLE OF NUMBER
  7        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  8
  9     varray_1         varray_test := varray_test ();
 10     nested_table1    nested_table_test := nested_table_test ();
 11     index_by_table1  index_by_table_test; -- := index_by_table_test ();   --> this
 12  BEGIN
 13     index_by_table1 (1) := 100;                                           --> this
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('DONE');
 15     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (index_by_table1 (1));                           --> result
 16  END;
 17  /
DONE
100                                                                           --> result

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```